# What are the PDFs of polar coordinates given independent Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: probability, distributions

Suppose that
$$
X \sim N(0,1) \\
Y \sim N(0,1)
$$
are i.i.d random variables that represent Cartesian coordinates. What are the marginal distributions of the polar coordinates $r$ and $p$?

What I have so far is
$$
f(r,p) = \frac{r}{2\pi} \cdot e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}
$$
but I am interested in the marginal PDFs $f(r)$ and $f(p)$.

Comment: The pdf of $r$ is the [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution#Relation_to_random_vector_length).

Comment: and the CDF of $\varphi$ would be some linear function of the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function)

Comment: @Spätzle: Sure about that?

Comment: You did find the joint density, *and that is not a function of the polar coordoinate*: Does thatb tel you something?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen first, this is the ratio of two independent standard normal RVs, which is the definition of Cauchy. Second, the angle parameter $\varphi$ is calculated as `arctan` of the ratio, so the CDF look somewhat like Cauchy (which is arctan as well). Third, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2836268/show-that-the-quotient-x-y-has-the-cauchy-distribution).

Comment: @Spätzle the 'arctan of a Cauchy distributed variable with location zero and scale one' is correct, but also a bit complex way to describe something that is simply a 'uniform distributed variable'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is simple to show that the Jacobian determinant of the mapping $(x,y) \mapsto (r, p)$ is $r$.  Consequently, you can write the joint density of the polar coordinates as:

$$\begin{align}
f(r, p) 
&= r \times f(x = r \sin p, y = r \cos p) \\[6pt]
&= r \times \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot \exp \Big( -\frac{r^2 (\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta)}{2} \Big) \cdot \mathbb{I}(r \geqslant 0, 0 \leqslant p \leqslant 2 \pi) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{r}{2\pi} \cdot \exp \Big( -\frac{r^2}{2}\Big) \cdot \mathbb{I}(r \geqslant 0, 0 \leqslant p \leqslant 2 \pi) \\[6pt]
&= r \cdot \exp \Big( -\frac{r^2}{2}\Big) \cdot \mathbb{I}(r \geqslant 0) \times \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot \mathbb{I}(0 \leqslant p \leqslant 2 \pi) \\[12pt]
&= \text{Rayleigh}(r|1) \cdot \text{U}(p|0,2\pi). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

This demonstrates that $r$ has a [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution) with unit scale and $p$ has a uniform distribution over the range of polar angles (and they are independent).

Comment: The efficiency and clarity of this computation is a gem.

Answer (score 6):

You can get to the result quickly by partitioning your equation into a product of a function of only $r$ and a function of only $p$.

$$f(r,p) = \frac{r}{2\pi} \cdot e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}} = f_R(r) \cdot f_P(p) \quad \text{for $r \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ and $p \in [0,2\pi)$}$$

with

$$\begin{array}{}
f_R(r) &=& r \cdot e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}& \quad \text{for $r \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$}\\
f_P(p)& =& \frac{1}{2\pi}& \quad  \text{for  $p \in [0,2\pi)$}
\end{array}$$

These are your marginal distributions.